# How to sort with linux command, while treat 3 lines as 1 block and sort based on the first line of each block

Tags: linux, sorting

How to sort with linux command, while treat 3 lines as 1 block and sort based on the first line of each block?

I know I can concat 3 lines into 1 line and then sort. But the file is simply too big, and I don't wan't to generate a temp file just for sorting.

Comment: example input/output please!

Comment: "I don't wan't to generate a temp file just for sorting." - it doesn't matter. For sorting the whole file will be read into memory *anyway*, you can't sort data in a "streaming" fashion. (Not technically true but since you're not sorting data using three tape drives on a system with extremely limited memory, this probably isn't relevant.) I'd just write a short Python (or whatever) script to do the custom sort, most of its time will be spent in IO and in the native sort implementation anyway.

Comment: @millimoose Creating a temp file can incur additional (and unnecessary) I/O time because, even in presence of OS-level caching, the system will eventually write out the temp file to physical storage. It also requires a safe writable location to store the file, and logistics to remove it when no longer needed (or when the program dies for any reason). It is quite understandable that the OP avoids temp files. As for saving memory, GNU sort supports the `-m` option for that purpose.

Comment: @user4815162342 You can still just pipe from the "line joining" program to `sort` I guess, gets rid of the wasted I/O

Comment: @millimoose Good point, and in fact I described that approach in my answer. Whether the OP was already aware of that option is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 3):

`sort` sorts lines of *text files*, where a record is always separated by newlines. As an exception, it does also supports `\0` as record separator, but there is no way to change *logic* of how the records are separated.

You can make use of the above exception to implement the *decorate-sort-undecorate* pattern, like this:

```
chunk | sort -z -t'
' -k1 | unchunk
```

`chunk` combines every three lines into `line1\0line2\0line3\n`, to allow `sort -z` to get the three-lined chunk as a single record, and `-t'\n' -k1` to sort by the first field in the record. `unchunk` just changes all `\0` back to `\n`.

Expressed in Perl, `chunk` would look like this:

```
perl -pe 'chomp;$_.=($.%3)?"\n":"\0"'
```

(A similar incantation could easily be written in `awk` or `sed`, and a C version would not be much longer.)

`unchunk` is no more than `tr '\0' '\n'`. Thus the complete sort is:

```
perl -pe 'chomp;$_.=($.%3)?"\n":"\0"' | sort -z -t'
' -k1 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Given the input file of

```
b
2nd b line
bla 3rd b line
a
some a line
other a line
x
first x line
other x line
```

...the above pipeline produces:

```
a
some a line
other a line
b
2nd b line
bla 3rd b line
x
first x line
other x line
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner does the job in bash.  It just reads the data into a perl array of triples of lines, sorts on the first line, then prints everything.

You can easily change the sort predicate to e.g. sort numerically (use `<=>` for this) or in any other manner you'd like.  This one uses lexicographic order.

To make it work in Windows, just switch the quotes:  Use "" on the outside and '' on the inside.

```
$ perl -e 'while(<>){push@a,[$_,scalar<>,scalar<>]}for(sort{$a->[0]cmp$b->[0]}@a){print join"",@$_}' < foo.txt
```

This assumes the input is in `foo.txt`.

Actually I just realized you can just concatenate rather than use the inner arrays. The result is even shorter!

```
$ perl -e 'while(<>){push@a,$_.scalar<>.scalar<>}for(sort @a){print}' < foo.txt
```